# How to check the condition of individual bytes stored in an address?

Tags: c, system, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int x = 2271560481; // 0x87654321

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {

unsigned char byte = *((unsigned char *)&x + i);


printf("Byte %d = %u\n", i, (unsigned)byte);
}


return 0;
```

}

For example I have this code right here displaying an output of :

```
Byte 0 = 33
Byte 1 = 67
Byte 2 = 101
Byte 3 = 135
```

How do I check the condition to see if the value is stored in the address?

Comment: `byte` only holds the last value after the loop. So yes you should store it in an array. You also have to define it outside of the for loop if you want to use it after.

Comment: How are you populating `byte[]` in your second code snippet? Please include an [mcve].

Comment: regarding: `int x = 2271560481;`  This causes the compiler to output: `untitled.c:5:9: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`  so the result is not what your expecting.

Comment: @user3629249 Why? `&x` is casted to `unsigned char *`. Type cast has higher precedence than addition.

Comment: Your right, my error.  I deleted the incorrect comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is loading one byte at a time into `byte` , its not a pointer so you cannot index off it. Do

```
unsigned char *bytePtr = ((unsigned char *)&x);

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
printf("Byte %d = %u\n", i, bytePtr[i]);
}
```

now you can do your test function using bytePtr

Comment: Should be `unsigned char *bytePtr = ...` no?

Comment: @pm100 You put "i" as type size_t should the printf be %zu instead of %d ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `byte` will hold last value. If you want to store all the values you need array.
Consider below example.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

    int x = 2271560481; // 0x87654321
    size_t i =0;
    unsigned char byte[sizeof x];
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {

        byte[i] = *((unsigned char *)&x + i);

        printf("Byte %d = %u\n", i, (unsigned)byte[i]);
      }

      if (byte[0] == 33 && byte[1] == 67 && byte[2] == 101 && byte[3] == 135) 
      {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```